# How can I create a db2 connection in Spring boot without use application.properties?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, db2, spring-jdbc

I need to build a connection to db2 database, but I can not use application.properties at this moment, so how can I create this connection?

Comment: Just create the datasource internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `datasource` bean in the app itself. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class MyClass {

  @Bean
  public DataSource getDataSource() {
    DataSourceBuilder<?> dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create();
    dataSourceBuilder.driverClassName(JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);
    dataSourceBuilder.url(myprops.getJDBCUrl());
    dataSourceBuilder.username(myprops.getJDBCUsername());
    dataSourceBuilder.password(myprops.getJDBCPassword());
    return dataSourceBuilder.build();
  }

}
```

Then, make sure any autowired references to the data source are "lazy", so the app has time to load the properties (maybe from another file) and to instantiate the data source, as in:

```
  @Lazy
  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;
```

Comment: That's a good idea, thank you, do you know if I can use ssl connection with datasource?

Comment: SSL **server** authentication is pretty easy. Just add the corresponding parameters in the JDBC URL. On the other hand, SSL **mutual** authentication is much more involved; see https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/complete-guide-set-ssl-using-ibm-data-server-driver-jdbc-and-sqlj